# Why is java.lang.Thread in the Google App Engine whitelist?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Why is `java.lang.Thread` in the [Google App Engine whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) when it is not supported?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thread is partially supported. For example, you can do

```
   Thread.sleep(1000);
```

However, App Engine doesn't allow you to create new thread in anyway. I guess it makes sense for the class to show up in whitelist.

Answer (score 2):

Only Google (or their employees) can give you the real reason, but my guess is that there are methods in that Class that you may use (such as [`getStackTrace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) or [`getContextClassLoader()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader())).

Comment: sorry can you elaborate, what getSTackTrace() and getContextClassLoader() for..?

Answer (score 2):

If jn.Thread was not whitelisted then any applications that make calls to Thread methods would fail. It's not supported because you cannot create your own threads using the jn.Thread class directly.  However you can create threads using the [app engine thread API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory%28%29).

Comment: Hi, thank your info, then how do we run the runnable by using google app API? you have any idea?